# How to check if a string has a letter in first and last in php

Tags: php, random

I have a program which create a random number with MH{random alphanumeric}K   format.

eg : MHmnwfJHJ1234K

How to check if the random number is in this format?

Comment: short answer: regex. this one should work: `"/MH\d+K/"`

Comment: string operations? regexes? print out the number and hire some people via mechanical turk to check for you? lots of options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions like so:

```
<?php
if(preg_match('/MH[0-9]+K/', 'MH123K')) {
    echo "Match!";
}
```

This one allows for any random number.

Comment: what if , if I need to have alphanumeric random string instead of random number?

Comment: Then you can use the expression ```MH[a-zA-Z0-9]+K``` or ```MH[[:alnum:]]+K```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
preg_match('/MH(\d+)K/', $subject, $matches)
```

https://www.php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have your generated string(number) in $randNum variable.
The simplest way would be this (but not the best way):

```
if($randNum[0]=="M" && $randNum[1]=="H" && $randNum[strlen($randNum)-1]=="K")
```

But the best way would be using regular expressions as @Allendar posted above me:

```
preg_match('/MH(\d+)K/', $subject, $matches)
```